# How do I get active working for bootstrap nav-pills

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4, shopify

I use bootsrap4 with shopify. I want to filter articles on the blog page by tag. I used `nav-pills` and want the `nav-link` to be active on the respective url.

With this code `active` class will not be passed. When I add `data-toggle="pill"` `active` will be passed, but the links don't work anymore and it is impossible to go to another url.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center mb-4">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-scroll nav-blog px-4">
        {% for tag in blog.all_tags %}
        {% if forloop.first == true %}
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link active pb-1 w-100" href="/blogs/{{ blog.handle }}">All</a>
            </li>
        {% else %}
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link pb-1 w-100" href="/blogs/{{ blog.handle }}/tagged/{{ tag }}">{{ tag }}</a>
            </li>
        {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you check in the javascript which class is being used for filtering? Shop output code also.